# Book ID: knife fighter with magic face tattoo

Tags: story-identification

The book has a male character that grows up in a rough community and becomes a great knife fighter. He has a tattoo that I think lights up when he fights. He runs away from home and goes on to become a wealthy merchant with a gypsy wife.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)